# Unable to backup files with long names in Windows 8 using 'File History'

Tags: windows-8, file-history

While trying to save copies of files for backup, I tried using 'File History' in 'Control Panel>>Security'.

I noticed that some of the files did not backup and are missing. On looking into it, it seems to happening with files with a longer file name but these are not more than the permissible  260 chars.

Is this a bug? How do I take backup?

Comment: Does Event Viewer have anything to say? What type of drive/filesystem are you using for File History?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the names of excluded files?

Comment: No error message. I am using and external NTFS HD.

Comment: @Matthew Simple filename with numerals and alphabets. Maximum filename is 238 in length.

Comment: @Kang: Thanks for your update. Consider adding it as an answer to this question, and accepting it (so it will be more visible to future visitors).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File History is adding 25 characters to the file name for date and time of the version, thus the total length is exceeding permits.

This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Or as MS would say, it's "by design". [Review](http://bit.ly/MimaK4): "It should be noted that File History is an incredibly naive tool. All it does is check the NTFS Change Journal (a file system-managed list of recently modified files), and then copy changed files to another drive. *For versioning, all it does is insert a timestamp into the filename.* ... You wouldn’t expect this kind of behavior from a dedicated backup tool, so I’m not quite sure why Microsoft has chosen such a rudimentary implementation for a built-in operating system tool."